# resize animation in flet framework (python)

Tags: python, animation, resize, desktop, flet

whenever I open my application made in the flet framework, from the python language, a resize animation is shown, because I changed the application's measurements. it happens pretty fast but I would like to remove that animation. how can I do this?
I apologize for any spelling mistakes, I'm Brazilian .

I tried several ways to solve it, but without success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because there is already a width default value in Page, so what you are really doing is resizing the window, this also happens with other things like the position of the window. What you can do is hide the window first, then change the width value, and finally show the window:

```
from flet import *

def main(page: Page):
   page.window_width = 100
   page.window_visible = True
   page.update()

app(target=main, view=FLET_APP_HIDDEN)
```